PHPMailer Connection whit Oauth2
I created some code to connect server side to gmail with Oauth2 but I get this error code:
2024-05-24 14:25:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP xxxxxx.114 - gsmtp
2024-05-24 14:25:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO services.*.it
2024-05-24 14:25:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [46.16.95.34]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2024-05-24 14:25:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2024-05-24 14:25:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2024-05-24 14:25:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO services.*.it
2024-05-24 14:25:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [xx.xx.xx.xx]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
2024-05-24 14:25:45 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2024-05-24 14:25:45 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection xxxxxx.114 - gsmtp

My code is as follows:
<?php

use Google\Client as Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Gmail;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\OAuth;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;

$clientId = 'xxxx'; 
$clientSecret = 'xxx'; 

$serviceAccountPath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config-email-noreply.json';

try {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig($serviceAccountPath);
    $client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);
    $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
    $tokenArray = $client->getAccessToken();
    $accessToken = $tokenArray['access_token'];
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->setOAuth(new OAuth([
        'provider' => new Google([
            'clientId' => $clientId,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
        ]),
        'clientId' => $client->getClientId(),
        'clientSecret' => $client->getClientSecret(),
        'refreshToken' => null,
        'accessToken' => $accessToken,
        'userName' => 'noreply@xxx.it',
    ]));

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';
    $mail->oauthUserEmail = 'noreply@xxx.it';
    $mail->oauthClientId = $client->getClientId();
    $mail->oauthClientSecret = $client->getClientSecret();
    $mail->oauthRefreshToken = null; 

    $mail->setFrom('noreply@xx.it', 'No-reply');
    $mail->addAddress('xxx@xxx.it', 'Recipient Name');
    $mail->Subject = 'Test email using OAuth2';
    $mail->Body = 'This is a test email sent using OAuth2 and PHPMailer.';


    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


This is my composer.json
{
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.9",
        "league/oauth2-google": "^3.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.14"
    }
}

(My php version is 8)
I can't find the error, can you help me? Thanks
I expected that if the token was returned to me, I would be able to send the message but phpmailer gives me an error

What error did you encounter?
Please provide more details about errors.

I think you need this as well:
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

